# search multiple value in query_string Elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, query-string, elasticsearch-5

I use these queries in elastic but the problem is when I replace values I get some different result or when I use each word individually we have different result.here is part of my queries

```
"query_string" : {
      "query" : "businessId : 1848 4335",
      "fields" : []
}
result : "hits": {"total": 81,....}
```

when replace businessIds:

```
"query_string" : {
      "query" : "businessId : 4335 1848",
      "fields" : []
}
result :  "hits": {"total": 162,...}
```

when I search "4335"

```
"query_string" : {
      "query" : "businessId : 4335",
      "fields" : []
}
result :  "hits": {"total": 0,...}
```

search "1848"

```
"query_string" : {
      "query" : "businessId : 1848",
      "fields" : []
}
result :  "hits": {"total": 14,...}
```

when I use "businessId" in fields

```
"query_string" : {
      "query" : "4335 1848",
      "fields" : ["businessId"]
}
result :  "hits": {"total": 14,...}
```

I am so confused why these results happened?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) like so:

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "businessId:4335 OR businessId:1848"
    }
  }
}
```

or

```json
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "businessId:(4335 OR 1848)"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you. but I know white space works as OR operator doesn't it?

Comment: Not sure about that one. I haven't seen your mapping... First of all, are we talking strings or numbers?